# How to tilt a label to forward side without changing its x coordinate

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

[image]

I want to make an animation like domino bricks falling on one another, as I want a label to be tilt to the forward side i.e. falling on another label (animation like effect). I am using the transform method but I don't know how it is done.I am getting confused in what should i change in coordinate.

Thanks in advance.

```
- (IBAction)moveButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{

        _brick1.transform =CGAffineTransformMake(_brick1.transform.a, _brick1.transform.b+5 , _brick1.transform.c , _brick1.transform.d, _brick1.transform.tx, _brick1.transform.ty);
     }];
```

}

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe you want to use Dynamics to archive domino effect. Nice tutorial: http://omarfouad.com/blog/2014/08/02/getting-started-uikitdynamics-swift/

Answer (score -1):

```
CALayer *layer = _brick1.layer;
layer.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(...)
```

Apply some 3D transform on your view layer.

Comment: can you explain how to do so

Comment: U can try some thing like this 
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
        
       CALayer *layer =_brick1.layer;
        CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m24 = 0.005;
        layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 50 * M_PI / 180.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }];
U can apply different angle and value as per ur need.

Comment: @VinayMaheshwari Don't put your answer in comments. Update your answer to include the needed code.